# How to set custom hint via Spring JPA annotation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, query-hints

In a project, I need to specify oracle hint in query. Spring JPA gives us to ability defining hint in @QueryHint (*javax.persistence*) annotation for query definition. But when I set oracle hint, app throws **Ignoring unrecognized query hint [hint-definition]** while query executes.

I found some question and answer 10 years ago or earlier than. They told you should be use native query. But I aim that code should be clean as possible.

How can specify custom query hint with JPA (or any Spring and Hibernate) annototion based on query?

> Note : In project, eclipselink is not used.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The query hint is for JPA/Hibernate NOT for the database. Are you execution native SQL?

Comment: Yes, I already solved with native SQL. EclipseLink gives us these funcionality that manipulete SQL its own QueryHints annotation. But I try to solve in JPA/Hibernate QueryHint annotation. If there is no solution without native SQL, I publish app with native SQL solution.